# Jquery DIV Popup

Tags: jquery, html, popup, focus

I have table with 20+ columns. Some columns have a Add link that would generate a popup in a div layer. The issue i'm having now is when I click on Add on columns that require scrolling to the right, it would create the popup but it would jump back to the first column and lose focus. How would I make sure it does not jump back to the first column and keep the focus where it was looking before click on Add?

```
$(function () {
    var moveLeft = 15;
    var moveDown = 20;

    $('a.trythis').click(function (e) {
        $('#popup').show().css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft).appendTo('body');

    });


    $('#closethis').click(function (e) {
        $('#popup').hide();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both click functions either `return false` or use `e.preventDefault()`.
This will stop the browser trying to follow the links (which are presumably `#`) and just apply the javascript